# Operate on multiple indices for numpy array using relational operators element wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that I can use a relational operator on my array to get a new array of Boolean values. The example below produces a boolean array with an identical shape to the original array but with `True` values if the item at the same index is greater than 0 and `False` otherwise.

```
>>> a = np. array ([ [0 , -2 ,5] , [ -1 , -8 , -12] ,[2 , 4, -9] ])
>>> z = a > 0
>>> print (a)
[[ 0 2 5]
[ 1 -8 -12]
[ 2 4 -9]]
>>> print (z)
[[ False True True ]
[ True False False ]
[ True True False ]]
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to simultaneously compare multiple indices to check if two or more values are greater than 0. For example, a line which would check each row to see if the first element and second element are greater than 0. Something than would look like

```
z = a[:,0] > 0 and a[:,1] > 0
```

And would produce the result

```
array([False, False,  True])
```

because a[0,1] = True but a[0,0] = False, a[1,0] = True but a[0,1] = False, and both a[2,0] and a[0,2] are True, thus returning False for the first row, False for the second row, and True for the third row

---

I want to do all of this without a loop

Comment: `np.logical_and(a[:, 0] > 0, a[:, 1] > 0)`?

Comment: `(a[:,0]>0) & (a[:,1]>0)` - group the comparisons with `()` and combine with an elementwise `&` (or `|`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

It will compute 'logical &' element wise.

```
np.logical_and(a[:,0] > 0, a[:,1] > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realize that the title to my question isn't very clear, can you think of a better title that would be more descriptive?

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly a loop:

```
[b[0] > 0 and b[1] > 0 for b in a]
```

Comment: but awfully close - the `for b in a` is an iteration.